# How to import bulk data into specified field in active directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, user-management

I have about 500 users in my AD and I need to Modify an specified field data.  But I don't want to do that one by one.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Poweshell is a great option to use and there are many scripts you can find on the internet etc... if you are not solid in powershell here is a utility you can use that is GUI based and works well to allow you to do CSV, XLS or direct modification of user accounts.

**Bulk AD Users by Wisesoft**

http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/software/bulkadusers/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're best suited using powershell.
There are a few good posts out there already about how to use powershell to update AD user fields.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ca04cdce-472a-4d29-a3c5-91285dc2dcd8/importcsv-to-update-active-directory-users